# Where to get worldwide City name, State/Province name, Postal/Zip code, Country, Latitude, Longitude data for free

Tags: geo, geocode, postal-code, geonames, postal

For this site "http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/" I cant get only 85 countries.
I referred "www.maxmind.com" they not provide postal/zip code.

Comment: @qqilihq I want worldwide but they provide only for 85 countries

Answer (score 0):

[openaddresses.io](https://openaddresses.io/) (provides street address data too)
[OpenstreetMap](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) Has more complete coverage. You can build queries to extraxt the data you need.

Comment: Its not cover all countries also latitude and longitude is missing

Comment: It is true that is does not cover all countries - it does cover quite a few. But the latitude and longitude must be there for those it covers.

Comment: See this link **http://results.openaddresses.io/?runs=all#runs** The green area is very less.